# How to add google Adsense to a Gatsby site?

Tags: gatsby, adsense

Google AdSense give me a script to added in the head tag

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

my code:

```
<Helmet>
  <script
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   async
   src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
   ></script>
</Helmet>
```

return me this error

**AdSense head tag doesn't support data-react-helmet attribute.**
how can I fix that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbVRl.png)

Comment: You don't need to fix it. It's a warning, not an error. It just tells that you AdSense JS will ignore that attribute. Usually data- attributes set on `<script>` tag used to change AdSense ads behavior. So that "head tag doesn't support" message is just to help developers detect errors if they misspelled attribute names.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau Thanks for you but sry I forget to add the image of console error can see it plz.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by adding the script to the html.js I need the head tag to be injected in a global context inside every page so I put it in the html.js file then I can add the body tag whenever I want.

Another way is to add the script in the gatsby-ssr.js like this:

```
const React = require("react")

const HeadComponents = [
 <script
   key="1-http-ads"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   async
   src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
   />,
]

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents(HeadComponents)
}
```